# Relativistic equations are medium dependent?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, refraction, maxwell-equations

Einstein proposed that light travels with a universal velocity from  Maxwell's equations on electromagnetism. But light has different velocity in different mediums, so does this imply that the relativistic equations are medium dependent?

Comment: No.  The speed of light in vacuum is the top speed.

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell's equations are medium dependent and they are also relativistic so in that case the answer is yes. Other equations are also called relativistic (equations describing particle motion either classical or quantum, for example)  and these are usually not considered medium dependent and c is the vacuum speed of light.  In these cases we introduce an interaction potential in place of a medium, and care is taken that the interaction potential satisfies appropriate relativistic transformations.